# Почему "в шутку" — раздельно, а "всерьёз" — слитно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, наречия

Сразу оговорюсь: такой вопрос уже был, но вместо ответа была написана какая-то белиберда. Поэтому хочу повторить вопрос.
У Розенталя я вычитала, что конструкция "предлог + существительное", отвечающая на вопрос "как", пишется слитно: *вдобавок, вброд, наперевес, наполовину* и т.д. Обе позиции — и "в шутку", и "всерьёз" — удовлетворяют этому правилу, и я не вижу разницы между тем же "вброд".
Там же приведено другое правило: слитно пишутся конструкции, ставшие устойчивыми и образовавшиеся давно (*вдоволь, вдребезги, взаперти*). И снова подходит.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между ***в шутку*** и ***всерьёз*** и почему они именно так пишутся?

Comment: В России и вообще на русском языке шутят мало по сравнению с разбиванием на мелкие кусочки, пересечением водных преград и разговорами на важные темы, вот поэтому-то не установилось ещё "вшутку" как устойчивое...

Comment: Добрый день.
Раньше, в девятнадцатом веке, а возможно и в начале двадцатого, "вшутку" писали слитно. Почему теперь пишут "в шутку", я не понимаю.

Comment: @Iliya Kuznetsov Ссылки, примеры?

Answer (score 1):

**Из словарей:**

**СЕРЬЁЗ,** -а; м. Разг. = серьёзность.
Докладывает, да с каким серьёзом!
Рассказать об этом на полном серьёзе (со всей серьёзностью, серьёзно).

**СЕРЬЁЗНЫЙ,**  [франц. *serieux (serieuse)*]
1. Отличающийся вдумчивостью и требовательностью к себе, к работе, к окружающим; глубокий, не легкомысленный.

Слова "серьёз, серьёзный" заимствованы в 18 веке, при этом существительное "серьёз" сначала использовалось в нейтральном стиле **и писалось раздельно в различных предложных сочетаниях:**

*Мы теперь на серьёзе разговор ведём* (Левитов. Аркадское семейство).
*Ведь я это советую не в серьёз, а только так для блезиру* (Лесков).
*Ловлю в её глазах — счастье, счастья — нет, есть страшный, детский смертный серьёз — девушки перед зеркалом* (Цветаева. Повесть о Сонечке).

Затем в нейтральном значении стали использоваться существительное "серьёзность", наречие "по-серьёзному", а слово "серьёз" стало выходить из употребления и было отнесено к разговорной речи.

**Изменилась и орфография.** При наличии зависимого слова мы имеем раздельное написание наречных выражений: для пущего серьёза, на полном серьёзе, **а наречие "всерьёз" пишется слитно. Почему?**
Возможно, слитная  форма связана с **малоупотребительностью** существительного, в то время как  наречие "всерьёз", имеющее пометку *разг.,* в действительности широко используется в различных стилях **(мы уже не воспринимаем "в серьёз" как падежную форму существительного "серьёз").**

**Что касается наречного выражения "в шутку"** — это обычная  форма направленного В. п. со значением цели, которая является обстоятельственным существительным и вряд ли когда-нибудь будет писаться слитно.

Comment: Замечательно про "серьёз", но крайне неполно и необоснованно про раздельное написание "в шутку", и полное игнорирование замечаний ОП про "вдребезги", "вдоволь", "взаперти".

Comment: Все то же самое. Дребезги, доволь и заперти – нет таких слов, за исключением, быть может, первого.

Comment: Вдребезги - аналогичное объяснение, можно разбить в щепки, в мелкие осколки, но "дребезги" не воспринимается как самостоятельное слово. Вдоволь и взаперти -  исходная падежная форма кратких прилагательных,  такие наречия всегда пишутся слитно, нет падежного управления (вправо, изредка и т.д.).

Comment: Это оно сейчас "не воспринимается".  А когда-то, возможно, "воспринималось"...  Так почему же "дребезги" ушли (оставив "дребезжать", например) а "шутка" не уйдёт?  Попытки предсказывать будущее - неблагодарное занятие, знаете ли...

Comment: Дребезги - это мелкие осколки, от дробить, а не дребезжать. Вот Вы "не узнали" слово,  не определили его  семантические связи, а хотите, чтобы оно писалось раздельно. Если для понимания слова нужен этимологический словарь, то это важный фактор, склоняющий нас к его слитному написанию.

Comment: По поводу последнего замечания относительно "в шутку". А как же быть с конструкцией "вброд"? По-моему, она аналогична, но пишется при этом слитно.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Ряд наречий в русском языке соотносятся с отглагольными существительными (или глаголами): брести – вброд, пролететь – напролёт, перекосить – наперекос, разладиться – вразлад, раскачать – враскачку, вытягивать – навытяжку. По значению они близки к деепричастиям: идти (как?) бредя по воде, сравнить: идти (куда?) в брод. Раздельное написание искажает значение наречного выражения, придавая ему ненужную направленность.

Answer (score 1):

> "в шутку" и "всерьез"...
>   **почему они именно так пишутся**?

Такова **традиция**. [См. ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1152#pp1152):

> **§ 139.** Во всех остальных (не регламентированных в § 136 — 138) случаях наречия (наречные сочетания) пишутся слитно либо раздельно,
>   причем их написание устанавливается в словарном порядке. **Написание
>   таких единиц не зависит ни от употребительности той части слова,
>   которая следует за предлогом-приставкой, ни от самого
>   предлога-приставки и определяется лишь письменной традицией.**
>   Подавляющее большинство этих наречий (наречных сочетаний) образованы
>   из предложно-падежных форм существительных или являются такими
>   формами.
>
> Ниже приводятся примеры наречий и наречных сочетаний по алфавиту
>   предлогов-приставок *в, за, к, на, от, по, с.* Слитное или раздельное
>   написание таких наречий и наречных сочетаний регламентируется
>   академическим «Русским орфографическим словарем». Напр.,
>
> **пишутся слитно**: *ввечеру, вволю, вгладь, вгорячах, вдоволь, вдобавок, взаймы, взаперти, вконец, влёт, вмиг, воистину, вовремя,
>   вокруг, вперевалку, вперегиб, вперемешку, вповалку, впопыхах,
>   впотьмах, впритык, впроголодь, впросак, впросонках, вразвалку,
>   вразброд, вразлад, вразрядку, врасплох, **всерьёз**, вслух, второпях;*
>
> **пишутся раздельно**: *в бегах, в глубину, в голос (кричать), в долг, в ладах, в насмешку, в нетях, в ногу, во благовремение, во всеоружии,
>   во всеуслышание, в пандан, в придачу, в разлив и в розлив, в
>   рассрочку, в розницу, в сердцах, в старину, в тягость, в ходу, в ходе,
>   **в шутку**...*

Comment: Непонятные вопросы люди задают: как, да зачем, да почему?  А решение простое: взял и выучил наизусть словарь Лопатина "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис?" Там всего-то  475 страниц, из них на букву В - 48 . Кстати говоря, традицией всё не объяснишь, формы написания слов менялись. Думали раньше академики, спорили, находили оптимальное решение, не то что сейчас. И вот что еще интересно: надо все предложные формы существительных учить или выборочно? Например: дети пришли (куда?) в школу. Обстоятельственное  значение у существительного, записать в словарь?

Comment: _Vera:  Кстати говоря, традицией всё не объяснишь_ === Ну не могут академики в отличие от нас просто взять и написать про "всерьез" так, как мы: _"возможно, слитная форма связана с малоупотребительностью существительного"_. Как тогда они смогут объяснить слитное написание таких наречий, как _вволю, вконец, вмиг, вовремя, вокруг, вразброд, вслух?.._  Тут-то про _малоупотребительность_ существительных не скажешь...

Comment: Давайте и без академиков будем отличать предлоги от приставок (этому ещё в первом классе учат, и смысл формы написания очень простой: слитно пишутся слова, а раздельно пишутся словосочетания). Давайте для слов, которые фактически не употребляются без приставки, выберем слитную форму написания как основную, объяснив способ образования слова, а все варианты с раздельным написанием будем считать исключением, предварительно объяснив их. Давайте построим определенную систему орфографии по этой теме, вместо того чтобы кивать на традицию и предлагать заучивать неопределенно большое количество слов.

Answer (score 1):

Все уже сказано, кроме ответа на последний вопрос, в чем разница. 
Разница в том, что слово "шутка" существует, а "серьез" пока еще не стало кодифицированным. По современным понятиям уже это может стать основанием для раздельного написания "в шутку". Именно "**может**", не требует императивно, но словарь закрепляет именно этот вариант.